# Match on user input pattern

Tags: macros, racket

I try to use `match` on user input pattern instead of having it static.

The idea is to expand:

```
(rule-match '(a (or '< '=) b) '(list a b) '(3 < 4))
```

To

```
(match '(3 < 5) [(list a (or '< '=) b) (list a b)])
```

I am not very familiar with macro and tried the following:

```
(define-syntax (rule-match stx)
  (syntax-case stx ()
    [(_ pat  act input )
     (with-syntax ([pattern-syntax (syntax (cons 'list pat))]
                   [action-syntax (syntax act)])
       #'(match input [pattern-syntax action-syntax]))]))
```

But get the error `match: no matching clause for '(3 < 4)`

Anyone have a hint on this?

Answer (score 1):

You're close.  The quote attached to your pattern is going to do strange things, though. Instead, just put the `list` in the pattern. Here's a snippet that does what I think you want:

```
#lang racket

(define-syntax (rule-match stx)
  (syntax-case stx ()
    [(_ pat  act input )
     (with-syntax ([pattern-syntax (syntax pat)]
                   [action-syntax (syntax act)])
       #'(match input [pattern-syntax action-syntax]))]))

(rule-match (list a (or '< '=) b) (list a b) '(3 < 4))
```

In fact, at this point, there's really no reason to separate out the two syntactic bindings, and you can just simplify to this:

```
#lang racket

(define-syntax (rule-match stx)
  (syntax-case stx ()
    [(_ pat  act input )
     #'(match input [pat act])]))

(rule-match (list a (or '< '=) b) (list a b) '(3 < 4))
```

... which I think you will agree is easier to read.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I need the use case where you have to pass a variable to the function `(rule-match some-var-pattern some-var-action input)` which I guess wouldn't work with this implementation.

Comment: erm... pass a variable? Can you elaborate your example to show what you mean?

Comment: Ah! you want the user to be able to pass patterns as run-time values? Sounds like you should just write your own pattern-matcher for that. Specifically, you're going to get into issues of hygiene; if you allow the user to pass in arbitrary patterns and templates, the obvious implementation won't be able to track hygiene.

Comment: honestly, though, as long as the user specifies the pattern and the template at the same place, you could design a "pattern-pair" macro that would bundle them together. Again, I think you'd better elaborate your example to show what you want.

Comment: Yea I will go for implementing my own pattern matching. The idea is to let user elaborate a set of pattern and iterate among them to see which one is matching.